# parse text file using json in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, json, parsing

How can i parse text file '.txt' stored in resource folder using 'JSON' parser in iphone? 
Any suggestions will be appreciated.
Thanks Neha Mehta.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/), and [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html).

Answer (score 2):

load the text file..and initialize the JSON..simple.

```
   NSString *textPAth = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"content" ofType:@"txt"];

    NSError *error;
    NSString *content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:textPAth encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];  //error checking omitted

    SBJsonParser *parser = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];

        NSDictionary *json = [parser objectWithString: content];
```